# How to calculate average daily / monthly pageviews in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

Is it possible to calculate the average daily pageviews or the average monthly pageviews for my website using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Audience > Overview
2. Select your desired date range (go from when you started your website if you want the figures for all-time)
3. Have a look at the total number pageviews, or another metric such as users
4. Divide this number by the amount of days (or months if you want to calculate the monthly value) in your range! You can calculate the amount of days in the range using online time and date sites.

Answer (score 3):

Daily average pageviews can be calculated in Google Data Studio as follows:

```
Pageviews / Count(Date)
```

Here is the formula for daily average pageviews by Users:

```
Users / Count(Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a custom metric, which you can then use in Custom reports, but you would only ever be able to use it in reports for specific time scales. That is, you can make a custom metric of pageviews/30, but it would only make sense when used in a report for a 30 day period.

You can also do this in Data Studio

Answer (score 0):

*This answer was provided by John Wedderburn and [copied](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/How-to-see-average-pageviews-per-month/td-p/835019) from the old Google Analytics product forum.*

Hi there - You're going to have to calculate this yourself. For reference, here's the complete list of all dimensions, metrics and calculated metrics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

One way to approach this would be to use the API to extract the information you need and then perform the calculation automatically. If you're a non-coder, the API is not as daunting as it sounds and there's an excellent ready made script which will help you get started: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oyb7yw_PNZs

Depending on your website, and the type of traffic you have, your average is possibly going to hide variation on the weekends vs weekdays. I'd be tempted to segment this further by using various segments e.g. weekdays, weekends, views of your most important content, views by customers etc